# Eloquent Builder Macro, get the relationship id

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm trying to add a macro for my query builder so I could have something like this

```
$person = Person::first();
$person->activity()->log("Newest Activity");
```

Unfortunately my implementation generates an error

> General error: 1364 Field 'person_id' doesn't have a default value

Here is my Implementation,I have a 2 class model,

one is Person Model

```
public class Person extends Model {

    public function activity()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Activity::class, "person_id");
    }

}
```

and ActivityLog Model

```
public class ActivityLog extends Model {

    public function newEloquentBuilder($query)
    {
        $builder = parent::newEloquentBuilder($query);

        $builder->macro('log', function (Builder $builder, $value) use ($query) {  
            return  $builder->getModel()
                ->newInstance([
                   'person_id' => // How to get the id from relationship
                   'details' => $value
                ])
                ->save();
        });

        return $builder;
    }
}
```

I know how to do it in laravels way, but I want to avoid specifying keys, this is one of the reason why I am doing this.

***How do I access the value of it person_id from the relationship, so that my implementation work?***

For more information, my table, this is how my table looks

```
Person Table

| Column       | Not Null | Auto Increment |
|--------------|----------|----------------|
| id           |    ✓     |      ✓        |
| first_name   |    ✓     |               | 
| last_name    |    ✓     |               |
| created_at   |          |                |
| updated_at   |          |                |



Activity Log Table

| Column       | Not Null | Auto Increment |
| id           |    ✓     |      ✓        |
| details      |    ✓     |                | 
| person_id    |    ✓     |                |
| created_at   |          |                |
| updated_at   |          |                |
```

My migration for activity log

```
Schema::create('activity_log', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('person_id');
    $table->string('details'); 
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

For someone, thinking why I am doing this,

this is the second reason why, I am planning to use `meta_key, meta_value`

here is the sample class

```
class FavoriteAnimalInfo extends Model
{
    //
    protected $table = "person_meta";

    protected $meta_key_name = 'favorite_animal';

    protected static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        static::creating(function ($model) {
            $model->meta_key = $model->meta_key_name;
        });
    }

    public function newEloquentBuilder($query)
    {
        $builder = parent::newEloquentBuilder($query);

        $builder->macro('add', function (Builder $builder, $value) {

            return  $builder->getModel()
                ->newInstance(['meta_value' => $value])
                ->save();
        });

        return $builder;
    }
}
```

Now my Person Class Could have something like this

```
public class Person extends Model {

    public function favoriteAnimal()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(FavoriteAnimalInfo::class, "person_id");
    }

}
```

And Now I can EasyLy Do this

```
$person = Person::first();
$person->favoriteAnimal()->add("dog");
$person->favoriteAnimal()->add("cat");
$person->favoriteAnimal()->add("chicken");
```